# VSTO Outlook: Catching Send Event

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to create plug-in that will catch any send item and show warning before sent out.
Currently I am using the below code

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
            
        }
```

However, I noticed it catches almost all the send event but when send button is pressed from main screen of Outlook, I mean when the mail is not popped out to separate window, it does not catch the event and my plugin function is not executed. My environment is Visual Studio 2019 and Outlook 2019. Any advise is appreciated.

Thank you,

Catch all the send event from Outlook.

Update 11/7/2022: it turned out that the event is caught but
I am tryning to catch the item type by the below method and inline item does not detected as an item.

```
itemtype = Application.ActiveWindow().CurrentItem.Class;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the `ItemSend` event is fired for all outgoing emails in Outlook, including inline responses. To make sure I've just created a sample VSTO add-in and placed your code there. Everything works correctly when I reply to items in-place. Try to declare the Application object at the class level. But I think everything should work as is now.

```
Outlook.Application application = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
            
        }
```

You may consider subscribing to the [Explorer.InlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.inlineresponse) event which is fired when the user performs an action that causes an inline response to appear in the Reading Pane. So, you may get the item composed and do whatever you need (subscribe to the `Send` event).

Be aware, a low level API such as Extended or Simple MAPI doesn't trigger the `ItemSend` event in Outlook - only actions made in the Outlook object model or made manually can trigger the event.

Comment: Hmmm, I will try again. Do you use Office 2019? I don't have another environment to test.....                 Thank you,

Comment: Yes, I do. It works for all Outlook versions.

Comment: I will check out further. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It should work in all cases, but Outlook disables most OOM events for the items created using Simple MAPI or from the "`mailto:"` links. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi, actually whenever I tried to reply/send from inline, not pop out window, it is not caught by the handler. Thank you,

Comment: Do you see the event fire in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - I am its author)? Click Application, go to the Events tab, look at the event log at the bottom of the window when you send a message.

Comment: Hello, let me try the tool and get back to you, the tool looks really useful!!

Comment: It did catch ItemSend (IDispatch, false) for both inline and popped out window!. So There should be something wrong with my code.....?

Comment: Does it help if you declare `application` variable on the class level rather than local?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, seems like I was using
itemtype = Application.ActiveWindow().CurrentItem.Class;
if I use
(int)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1].Class
I can get the type of item and process with in the function.
it seems little more dangerous than the upper code since it assumes always at the 1st one in the selection,,,,, 

Thank you,

Comment: (int)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] points to random thing so I need to dig how to get active item regardless of inline or popped out. Thank you,

Comment: So the problem was the event handler? Why do you even need the currently displayed/selected item? The item being sent is passed to your event handler.

Comment: Yes just realized..... it's one of the arguments, obj Item, right? How could I tell if this is mailitem, taskitem, etc? I was using Olobject class number to enumerate before. but not sure how to tell it from object class... Thank you,

Comment: I think the original question is clear. I will ask in the new thread about digging into send function's argument. Thank you!

Comment: Check the Class property - it will be 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail) for the regular messages